# How quickly do my Friends regenerate?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

In FFBE, I have a list of friends, all specifically chosen for their abilities, both supportive and offensive. However, after using them, I have to wait until they become available again.

How long do I have to wait until my Friends become available for use again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My tests tends to show a *used* friend become available again after changing three times the hour of the day.

Example : if you use a friend at 05:20 PM, it will become available at 08:00 PM.

Comment: Sorry, do you mean that the character becomes available again after 3 hours? The example you provided is unclear

Comment: I think I get it: it doesn't refresh after 3 hours (or 180 minutes) but rather "on the hour"

Comment: yes, it is always "on the hour", when reaching 00 minutes. So you need 121 minutes min to 180 minutes max for the friend to refresh. I do not know how to explain this better than "changing three times the hour of the day" XD